# How to append to host file on remote machine using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

From time to time I need to edit host files on remote machines. It would make things much easier if I could use a quick vbscript for this. The script that I'm working on isn't making the changes and I'm not too sure why.

```
on error resume next
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strComputer   = inputbox("Enter remote computer name or leave as localhost for this computer","Get Hosts file","Localhost")
If strComputer = "" Then
    WScript.Quit
End If

HostsFile = strComputer & "\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\Hosts" 

Set filetxt = fso.OpenTextFile(HostsFile, ForAppending, True)
DNSEntry = inputbox("Enter the DNS entry" & vbCrLf & "ex: 192.168.0.2         domain.com","DNSEntry")
If DNSEntry = "" Then
    WScript.quit
Else
filetxt.WriteLine(DNSEntry)
filetxt.Close 
End If

WScript.quit
```

Comment: Get rid of the evil global OERN.

Comment: commented that out and still no good.

Comment: but you would get an error message.

Comment: actually i don't get any errors. the code goes through as if it works but doesn't work. i used msgboxes to see where the code is and returns what it's doing and it appears to be working. just doesn't.

Comment: What is the value of `HostsFile` right before you try to open that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're planning on using an administrative share, change this line:

```
HostsFile = strComputer & "\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\Hosts"
```

to

```
HostsFile = "\\" & strComputer & "\c$\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\Hosts"
```